# Mvc4 installer is incompatible with .net 4.5 but .net 4.5 is not installed

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010

I'm getting the classic 'mvc4 installer is incompatible with .net 4.5' that many others have gotten except I do not have .Net 4.5 installed on this machine. MVC3 projects getting created just fine. I get this error when running the Web Installer for MVC4 Beta.

System setup is VS2010 SP1, Windows 7 64-bit, Resharper is installed as well

I am at a loss here and now seem to be just wasting time trying to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as if the new MVC4 RC fixed my problem. So goes life with Beta software.